# Unpack GROUP BY query for results that lack the key?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to run a GROUP BY query to select all the items in a table grouping them by a collection id.

```
| id | collection | date |
|  1 | x          | ...  |
|  2 | x          | ...  |
|  3 | y          | ...  |
|  4 |            | ...  |
|  5 |            | ...  |
```

I'd like to obtain a list like this:

```
[
  {
    collection: x,
    items: [1, 2]
  },
  {
    collection: y,
    items: [3]
  },
  {
    collection: null,
    items: [4]
  },
  {
    collection: null,
    items: [5]
  }
]
```

My query right now is the following, but I need a way to unpack items that lack the collection ID so that they all end up in a separate group, how can I do?

```
SELECT id, collection FROM items ORDER BY date DESC GROUP BY collection
```

I'm using MySQL but any SQL syntax would still be helpful.

Comment: do you need a json output ?

Comment: No it's just an example, anything works, I'm just trying to understand how a query like this would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I have shared two query. One with conditional group by clause and the other one is using union all. I would prefer first one.

```
 CREATE TABLE items( id int, collection varchar(10));
 insert into items values(  1 , 'x');
 insert into items values(  2 , 'x');
 insert into items values(  3 , 'y');
 insert into items (id)values(  4     );
 insert into items (id)values(  5     );
```

Query#1 (conditional group by clause)

```
 SELECT collection,group_concat(id) id FROM items  
 GROUP BY collection,
 case when collection is not null then collection else id end
```

Output:

| collection | id |
| --- | --- |
| null | 4 |
| null | 5 |
| x | 1,2 |
| y | 3 |

Query#2 (using union all)

```
 SELECT collection,group_concat(id) id FROM items  where collection is not null
 GROUP BY collection 
 union all
 select collection,id from items where collection is null
```

Output:

| collection | id |
| --- | --- |
| x | 1,2 |
| y | 3 |
| null | 4 |
| null | 5 |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=dbf2d36df6faf94f9e4cae471f30e7f7)*

**Sorted by collection and id:**

Query#1

SELECT collection,group_concat(id) id FROM items
GROUP BY collection,
case when collection is not null then collection else id end
order by collection,id

Output:

| collection | id |
| --- | --- |
| null | 4 |
| null | 5 |
| x | 1,2 |
| y | 3 |

Query#2

```
 select collection,id from 
 (
   SELECT collection,group_concat(id) id FROM items  where collection is not null
   GROUP BY collection 
   union all
   select collection,id from items where collection is null
 )t  order by collection,id
```

Output:

| collection | id |
| --- | --- |
| null | 4 |
| null | 5 |
| x | 1,2 |
| y | 3 |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1da515521b9ca3c7d2823f83dbd00036)*

Comment: Please check the order by clause. Is it ok?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
   CASE WHEN collection is null THEN id ELSE collection END as id, 
   GROUP_CONCAT(collection) as collection
FROM items 
GROUP BY 1
```

I see, you have an `ORDER BY date`?

Comment: I still need to be able to ORDER BY date (or any other column I may have)

Comment: It is unclear why you need the `order by`. The data is not in the result...

Comment: I just need to display the most recent data first

Comment: ok, that will be hard to get, if you have `sql_mode=only_full_group_by` like I have now...